# Insert whole source xml into attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

Source xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <B>b</B>
    <C>c</C>
</ROOT>
```

I need the result xml to look like (the value of attribute **file** should contain whole source xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RD801>
    <C801 code="b" file="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?    &gt;&#xA;&lt;**ROOT**&gt;&#xA; &lt;B&gt;b&lt;/B&gt;&#xA; &lt;C&gt;c&lt;/C;&#xA;&lt;/ROOT&gt;"/>
</RD801>
```

**Could anyone please help me build proper xslt file to transform source xml into the resulting xml file. I will be greatful**
The main problem is to insert whole source xml into attribute value. Do I need serialize?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please share what you have so far.

Comment: The best way to do this is not to. Why would you want to take a perfectly good XML document and turn it into junk? Of course, your next question will be how to parse the XML remnants stored in the `file` attribute - and the answer will be somewhere between very difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 1):

If your source XML has no attributes, you can use this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="data">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <RD801>
            <C801 code="b">
                <xsl:attribute name="file">
                    <xsl:text>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&#xA;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$data" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </C801>
        </RD801>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your source has attributes, comments, processing instructions, etc. you will have to write templates to deal with them. You can use the stylesheet above as a starting point.

Here is a [working example](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHR).